# Broken table values, how do i fix it?

Tags: java, swing, null, jtable

It seems that after I designed my table, it turns the values in my table into "squares" and some of the values in my other table simply disappear.

I'm pretty sure my database is connected and updated. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix it? My data come from Phpmyadmin/SQL.
Also, I am using Java Swing to design the tables.

Image of th evalues becoming squares:

[image: Value becoming squares]

This is all the method code I used for the first picture:

```
 public void TampilData(){
        DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("Nama Obat");
        model.addColumn("Tipe Obat");
        model.addColumn("Batas Beli");
        model.addColumn("Harga Persatuan");
        
        try{
        String sql="SELECT Nama_obat, "
                + "Tipe_obat, Batas_beli, "
                + "harga, id_obat FROM obat WHERE nama_obat like '"+Search.getText()+"%'"
                + " AND NOT Jumlah_stok < 3";
        java.sql.Connection conn=(Connection)Config.configDB();
        java.sql.Statement stm=conn.createStatement();
        java.sql.ResultSet res=stm.executeQuery(sql);
        
    while (res.next()){
        model.addRow(new Object[]{
            res.getString(1),
            res.getString(2),
            res.getString(3),
            res.getString(4),
            res.getString(5)});
        }
        tabel_obat.setModel(model);
        
    }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
    }
        
    }
 private void SearchActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}                                      

private void tabel_obatMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    int baris=tabel_obat.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    String nama=tabel_obat.getValueAt(baris, 0).toString();
    namaobat.setText(nama);
    String tipe=tabel_obat.getValueAt(baris, 1).toString();
    String jmlh=tabel_obat.getValueAt(baris, 2).toString();
    DefaultComboBoxModel cmodel = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
    for(int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(jmlh); i++){
        cmodel.addElement(i+1);
    }
    ComboBuy.setModel(cmodel);
    
    String harga=tabel_obat.getValueAt(baris, 3).toString();
    price = Integer.parseInt(harga);
    TotalHarga.setText(price+"");
    
    try{
    String sql="SELECT id_obat FROM obat WHERE nama_obat = '"+nama+"' "
            + "AND Batas_beli = "+jmlh+" AND Tipe_obat = '"+tipe+ "' AND Harga = "+harga;
    java.sql.Connection conn=(Connection)Config.configDB();
    java.sql.Statement stm=conn.createStatement();
    java.sql.ResultSet res=stm.executeQuery(sql);
        while(res.next()){
            Data_Checkout.setId_obat(res.getInt(1));
        }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
}
    
}   

 private void ComboBuyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    TotalHarga.setText(price*(ComboBuy.getSelectedIndex()+1)+"");
}                                        

private void SearchKeyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
    TampilData();
}                               

private void nextButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     if(namaobat.getText().equals("---Pilih Obat---")){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Pilih Obat terlebih dahulu");
    }else{
        Data_Checkout.setNama_obat(namaobat.getText());
        Data_Checkout.setJumlah(ComboBuy.getSelectedIndex()+1);
        Data_Checkout.setTotal(TotalHarga.getText());
        
        
        this.setVisible(false);
        new Checkout().setVisible(true);
    }
}                                       

private void jLabel7MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                     
    // TODO add your handling code here:
      this.setVisible(false);
    new LoginScreen().setVisible(true);
}
```

Image of values that disappear:

[image: Some value dissapearing]

This is all the code for the second picture:

```
public void TampilData(){
        DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel();
        model.addColumn("NIK");
        model.addColumn("Nama Lengkap");
        model.addColumn("Jenis Kelamin");
        model.addColumn("Tanggal Lahir");
        model.addColumn("Password");
        
        try{
    String sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE nik like '"+txtCari.getText()+"%'";
    java.sql.Connection conn=(Connection)Config.configDB();
    java.sql.Statement stm=conn.createStatement();
    java.sql.ResultSet res=stm.executeQuery(sql);
    
    while (res.next()){
        model.addRow(new Object[]{
            res.getString(1),
            res.getString(2),
            res.getString(3),
            res.getString(4),
            res.getString(5)});
        }
        tabel_user.setModel(model);
        
    }catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("Error "+e.getMessage());
    }
    }

    private void tabel_userMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        

        int baris=tabel_user.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        nik=tabel_user.getValueAt(baris, 0).toString();
        String nama=tabel_user.getValueAt(baris, 1).toString();
        txtNamaLengkap.setText(nama);
        String jeniskelamin=tabel_user.getValueAt(baris, 2).toString();
        if(jeniskelamin.equals("Pria")){
            button_pria.setSelected(true);
            button_wanita.setSelected(false);
        }
        else if(jeniskelamin.equals("Wanita")){
            button_pria.setSelected(false);
            button_wanita.setSelected(true);
        }
        
        try{
        String tgl=tabel_user.getValueAt(baris, 3).toString();
        Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(tgl);
        txtTanggal.setDate(date1);
        }
        catch (Exception e){}
        
        String pass=tabel_user.getValueAt(baris, 4).toString();
        txtPassword.setText(pass);
        
    }
```

I can't put all of the code of the class here because it is so much.

Comment: The font you're using is missing the proper glyphs to display unicode characters. You should edit your question to indicate where your data is coming from, because you're going to have to set the proper encoding at some point. Also, get in the habit of including relevant code when you post a question to save all the back and forth of people having to ask you for things that you should have included initially. People occasionally get bored with waiting and wander off before giving you a definitive answer. Remember: you're asking for free help, so make it easy for others to do so.

Comment: Ohh okay sorry im still new to stackoverflow i will try to show codes from now on